# Use nullable or undefineable as object type?

Tags: javascript, null, typescript

This come with a debate with my colleague that I'm using nullable object type.

```
  type Value = Node | null
  const [v0, setV0] = React.useState<Value>(null)
  const [v1, setV1] = React.useState<Value>(null)

  const snapshot = (nodes: Node[]) => {
    const root = Parser.parse(nodes)
    if (v0 === null) {
      setV0(root)
    } else if (v1 === null) {
      setV1(root)
    } else {
      setV0(v1)
      setV1(root)
    }
    alert("current version saved!")
  }
```

He's suggestion is change it to undefinable object type. `type Value = Node | undefined` since [null is a mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare)

My understanding with `undefined` type in JS is a preserve type for *item not found*. ie,

```
object['not exist'] === undefined
array[-1] === undefined
```

With his suggestion we cannot distinguish if

```
type object = { [key: string]: Value }
object['not exist'] === undefined
const a: Value = object['not exist']
```

Also many libraries like lodash treat undefined and null differently. So I'm worried if this can cause problems later on.

Comment: If null is a mistake, then `Node | undefined` is the same sort of a mistake, for the same reason - it's only that it's slightly different in flavor. So your colleague's argument kind of doesn't hold up. But see what semantically makes more sense - `null` or `undefined` - and consider how your type is going to be used.

Comment: Undefined is a variable that has been declared but not assigned a value. null is an object. Its type is object. null is a special value meaning "no value. undefined is not an object, it's type is undefined.use according to how your variable type is.

Answer (score 3):

Undefined usually signifies that a property does not exist at all. For example, as you showed, attempting to access a missing property yields undefined. This is because the property itself does not exist; it is not valid.

Null on the other hand signifies that a property exists, but has no value. If it is legal within your program for a value to be optionally present (which appears to be the case in your specific example), then go with null since that better communicates that the property exists but is empty.